# Django: raw passwords via request.POST

Tags: python, django

This question concerns the standard `UserCreationForm` within Django, and the way that passwords are stored, extracted and used through a `request object`. Specifically the fact that I seem to be able to print raw passwords through `print(request.POST)`. File contents will be provided at the end of this post.

I have created a registration page. I have set up a very basic `class-based view` that authenticates and logs the newly created user in. The actual `HTML` of that page is rendered automatically in this case, through `{{ form.as_p }}` where form is an instance of `UserCreationForm`.

How come, when I execute print(request.POST), I get something along the lines of this returned:

```
<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['keeping_this_private'], 'username': ['William'], 'password1': ['ACTUALPASSWORD'], 'password2': ['ACTUALPASSWORD'], 'button': ['']}>
```

Is this really secure? As I have only been programming for a couple of months, I am still learning.

**Views.py:**

```
class RegisterView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        form = UserCreationForm()
        return render(request, 'authentication/registration.html', {'form': form})

    def post(self, request):
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print(request.POST)
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')

        else:
            return render(request, 'authentication/registration.html', {'form': form})
```

**Registration.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block body %}
<body class="text-center">
  <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}

    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit" name="button"></button>

  </form>
</body>
{% endblock %}
```

**Urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^register/$', RegisterView.as_view(), name='register'),
    ...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes this is absolutely expected. When a user submits a password in a form, it is submitted as is (clear). There is no other choice, you need the clear password to be able to check its validity. The transport of the POST data should however be secured with HTTPS protocol.

You could be tempted to hash it on the client side before sending it to your server. It is however not increasing security at all as in this case, the hashed version of the password, becomes the actual password. It is a common **false** security feeling.

I invite you to read [this post on security.stackexchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/64631/is-it-safe-to-send-clear-usernames-passwords-on-a-https-connection-to-authentica) for more details

Comment: Could you hash the password with a pre-agreed salt on the client side to avoid this issue?  The salt should be sent by the server, and change on every request. That way, intercepting the hash would be useless, as it would only be valid for that specific request.

Comment: Thank you for a very precise answer. Is the HTTPS protocol automatically taken care of by Django? And do I really need to use the form-widgets? Or can I just write my own HTML as long as the basic requirements for each input is intact ('name' the same as the Django-generated HTML etc) - and then just use the forms for validation? Without loosing any security?

Comment: @TomOldbury That's a good question. I think it would work theoretically, but would be somewhat a pain to setup in practice. I invite you to do a research on the internet or ask on security.stackexchange.com if you can't find anything. Also, I'd say that if someone is able to intercept the password eventhough you're using a proper HTTPS connection, finding a flaw to exploit it might be a piece of cake.

Comment: @WilliamKarlsson, setting up Django to support HTTPS is quite easy https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/security/#ssl-https You should however configure your web server (ie. nginx or apache) to use HTTPS and generate SSL certificates.

Answer (score 3):

That's a good question, specially from someone new to programming. The fact is that it's, basically, totally insecure - but unavoidable. Passing a hashed password would actually be just as insecure since anyone (well, anyone able to read the packet at least) could still read the post content, and you do need to send the password from the user's client to your server one way or another. Note that you'll have the very same issue with just any confidential information actually, not only passwords.

The solution here is to [use https](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS) instead of http so the request's body is encrypted. It's still not 100% safe and secure (nothing is actually 100% safe and secure) but a brut force attack would either require too much resources or too much time.